# SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT not working after installing the app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a problem to lock the orientation of my app in portrait mode. I added `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` and `android:configChanges="orientation"` to my Manifest. Moreover, I added `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)` in the `onCreate(...)` of my `MainActivity`. The `MainActivity` is extended by `AppCompatActivity`. At any time, it works, so you never see your app in the landscape orientation, except when you install it for the first time on your device. Then it is possible to change between landscape and portrait orientation. Does anybody know why this happens? Thank you in advance.

Comment: remove config changes propert of activity from manifest

Answer (score 0):

Don't apply the orientation to the application element, instead you should apply the attribute to the activity element, and you must also set configChanges as noted below.

Example:

```
<activity
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
</activity>
```

This is applied in the `manifest` file AndroidManifest.xml.